# Using procedures as model parameters

Tags: netlogo

I'm building a model that compares search functions.

I can manually change the code to refer to a different search procedure but I'd like to use behavior space to run my trials so optimally I would have a parameter that directs the model to call a procedure as a function of the parameter.

so for 4 search functions: a, b, c, d

I can just use a "wrapper" reporter like below, but just wanted to see if there were better ways to handle this in netlogo.

The search function is called about n! - (0.5n)! times where n is the number of turtles so the wrapper function isn't an awesome thing to have to add as it's pretty inefficient.

I'm not aware of being able to use procedures as arguments in netlogo, is there a way to do that?

```
to-report wrap [function-type]

ifelse function-type = 1
[
    report a
]
[
    ifelse function-type = 2
    [
        report b
    ]
    [
        ifelse function-type = 3
        [
            report c
        ]
        [
            ifelse function-type = 4
            [
                report d
            ]
            [
                report "not a valid function type"
                ; or some sort of error value
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with geruter about using BehaviorSpace. I'm not sure that I understand fully why their answer doesn't quite get at what you need, but maybe this will work for you.

Assuming you have a chooser or a slider called `function-selected` on your interface, you can store the desired procedure name as a string, then use `run` to have the turtles evaluate that string. Here is a simple example:

```
globals [ function ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [ pd ]
  choose-func  
  reset-ticks
end

to choose-func
  if function-selected = 1 [
    set function "move-1"
  ]
  if function-selected = 2 [
      set function "move-2"
  ] 
  if function-selected = 3 [
      set function "move-3"
  ] 
end
```

There, the function of choice as determined by the `function-selected` slider is used in `setup` to store the name of one of three procedures. Now your turtles can just call `run function` and they will evaluate the string value stored in `function` to call the appropriate procedure:

```
to go 
  ask turtles [
    run function
  ]
  tick
end

to move-1
  rt 5 
  fd 1
end

to move-2
  rt 30
  fd 1
end

to move-3
  rt random 61 - 30
  fd 1
end
```

With `function-selected` set to 1 at `setup`:

[image]

With `function-selected` set to 2 at `setup`:

[image]

With `function-selected` set to 3 at `setup`:

[image]

If you want it to be a little more flexible (like if the search type chosen needs to vary by turtle or with time, you might make use of the table extension:

```
extensions [ table ]

globals [ function-dict ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [ pd ]
  set function-dict table:make 
  table:put function-dict 1 "move-1"
  table:put function-dict 2 "move-2"
  table:put function-dict 3 "move-3"
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  ask turtles [
    run table:get function-dict function-selected
  ]
  tick
end

to move-1
  rt 5 
  fd 1
end

to move-2
  rt 30
  fd 1
end

to move-3
  rt random 61 - 30
  fd 1
end
```

Comment: yeah this is different from the other answer because `choose-func` can be evaluated once per trial with the result used thereafter whereas an `if` solution like mine or geruter's  has to be evaluated each time the generic search function is called. In other languages this can be handled by using a function as a parameter of another function. Using a function as a global variable like this is almost the same thing.

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley - Gotcha, makes sense. Glad this does what you need!

Comment: and just to add in here for posterity, if someone is using a reporter rather than a procedure, all they have to change in the above code is `run` to `runresult`

Comment: Very good answer. I was not aware that you could pass a function as a paramter with `run` and `runresult`. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do your experiments with Behaviour Space, I would recommend you create a Chooser in the Interface Tab of Netlogo ( check Screenshot below). There you enter the names of your search procedures (Screen2). Than you can select them in Behaviour Space and run subsequently experiments on it (Screen3).

Screen1

[image: Screenshot 1]

Screen2

[image: Screenshot2]

Screen3

[image: Screenshot3]

The lines below must be included in your code to tell Netlogo, which procedure should be applied given the value of the chooser `proc`. For example, if you select `"a"` from the chooser, that the procedure `test1` will be executed:

```
to go

  if proc = "a" [ test1 ]
  if proc = "b" [ test2 ]
  if proc = "c" [ test3 ]
  if proc = "d" [ test4 ]

end
```

I hope, this works for you!

Comment: yeah the chooser box looks promising, the interaction between the interface and the code in netlogo is probably the trickiest part.

Comment: My problem is that I have a `go` procedure that calls procedures, several of which call the search procedure being used. So I need to be able to call the correct procedure from several different scopes, not just once as the observer

Comment: As long as the search procedures don´t change within one run, say they are predetermined at the setup phase, you can use the code above at any point of your go procedure whenever the search procedure should be applied. Actually it does the same as your wrapper function. The problem is that a to-report as the wrapper function form above only reports back numbers or strings, but you can´t report back other procedures for execution. Apart from this, I have no other idea on how to help you, but maybe the other experts here can :)

Comment: yeah, my original code works for that, the goal is to only have to call the code that determines search type once for efficiency. 5 `if`s is a lot for a high number of trials*ticks